# How to copy docx file header image into anoter docx file in java

Tags: java, docx4j

I am using `docx4j api` for creating `docx` file. I am successfully copied one `docx` content to another. 
For copy header content, i get header text.
But my requirement is also copy header image. how can i do this?
I am using below code to copy header-

```
 WordprocessingMLPackage source = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(
                        "D://PoC//Agenda Formats//test.docx"));
                RelationshipsPart rp = source.getMainDocumentPart()
                                .getRelationshipsPart();
 Relationship rel = rp.getRelationshipByType(Namespaces.HEADER);
 HeaderPart headerPart = (HeaderPart)rp.getPart(rel);
HeaderPart newHeaderPart = new HeaderPart();
newHeaderPart.setContents(XmlUtils.deepCopy(headerPart.getContents()));
return wordprocessingMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(
                                newHeaderPart, AddPartBehaviour.RENAME_IF_NAME_EXISTS);
```

but this code not copy image. any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to copy over each rel of the header.  So iterate through its relationships, and copy each part.  In this case you can use addTargetPart to add it with the same relId.  This way, you won't have to change the relId in the header content.   You should be able to find some sample code using Google, but if you are still having issues, just say so :-)

Comment: i am struggling from yesterday but not getting any code.please if you have then post code for same.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (untested):

```
void attachHeader(HeaderPart sourcePart, WordprocessingMLPackage targetPkg) throws Docx4JException {

    HeaderPart newHeaderPart = new HeaderPart();
    newHeaderPart.setContents(XmlUtils.deepCopy(sourcePart.getContents()));

    if (sourcePart.getRelationshipsPart()!=null) {

        // clone the rels part
        RelationshipsPart rp = sourcePart.getRelationshipsPart();
        newHeaderPart.getRelationshipsPart(true).setContents(XmlUtils.deepCopy(rp.getContents()));

        // copy/add each part
        for (Relationship r : newHeaderPart.getRelationshipsPart().getContents().getRelationship()) {

            // get the source part
            Part part = sourcePart.getRelationshipsPart().getPart(r.getId());

            // ensure it is loaded
            if (part instanceof BinaryPart) {
                ((BinaryPart)part).getBuffer();
            }

            // You might need to clone this part depending on your use case, but here I'll just attach it to targetPkg              
            targetPkg.getParts().getParts().put(part.getPartName(), part);
                // This simple approach won't work if the target package already contains a part with the same name 
                // To fix that, you'd need to rename the part (also in the rel)

            part.setPackage(targetPkg);
            part.setOwningRelationshipPart(newHeaderPart.getRelationshipsPart());

        }

    }
    targetPkg.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(newHeaderPart,
            AddPartBehaviour.RENAME_IF_NAME_EXISTS);        
}
```

Comment: i am using enterprise version but i am able to read images using above code. please help.

Comment: With the Enterprise version, just add a BlockRange containing the sectPr with the header of interest.  It will do the rest.

Comment: Please provide some example

Comment: please provide example its very urgent.

Comment: you can email support@plutext.com but when you do so please explain your overall objective and attach the relevant docx files